# TFS / Azure DevOps : perliminary SA subtask makes PBI displayed in the wrong Sprint

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, agile, scrum, sprint

Working with TFS / Azure DevOps.
To better describe the issue, lets say current Sprint is 52
We create a PBI under the next Sprint (for example: 53), then the System Analyst creates a subtask under that PBI for themselves to create technical specs.
Obviously they should work on those specs in current Sprint (52), so they set the iteration for that subtask to Sprint 52 (the subtask is a child of the PBI)

As a result, under 'Sprint' section, we can no longer find the PBI in Sprint 53, it is displayed as part of 52 messing everything around...

Any ideas ??

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**A PBI is intended to be a unit of work that can be accomplished within a single sprint/iteration.**  A Feature tracks multiple PBIs, potentially across sprints.

If you want to move,  usually you could open ‘Planning’ at side pane and drag the parent task to sprints that you want to move. Also you could right click parent task to select ‘Move to iteration’.

As it supposed to be, this operation will move them( subtasks) together.  That's not a common scenario, use a PBI in one sprint and create child tasks of that PBI in another sprint.

Simply create another PBI to track should be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, a PBI is a unit of work that has to be completed in 1 Sprint.
In some cases like this, where the technical specs or R&D task need to be performed before commencement of any other task on the PBI, the PBI would span across multiple Sprints. 
You can always create a corresponding PBI as a parent for each task in each Sprint until the PBI/ User story is done to completion.